# Почему не работает клавиатура?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine

Установил игру (cs source) с помощью playonlinux. Настроил wine таким образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю игру в оконном режиме (в полноэкранном пробовал), и не работает клавиатура. Просмотрел, много форумов, не нашёл ответ. Опытные пользователи подскажите.

Comment: А зачем устанавливать cs source в wine, если есть нативная версия для линукса?

Comment: Нативно, вы имеете ввиду платно через steam?

Comment: Во-первых, надо было по скидкам за 25 рублей покупать, во-вторых мы же все прекрасно знаем, что есть множество ресурсов, где всё можно скачать бесплатно ‍☠️‍☠️‍☠️

Comment: А вы не знали, что в цивилизованном мире труд оплачивается?!